# The remote server returned an error :(403) Forbidden - C#

Tags: c#

I keep getting a 403 error when i run this code has anyone got an idea how I can fix this I tried some of the other fixes posted to this site but they didn't seem to work any help would be appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://www.bom.gov.au/vic/forecasts/ballarat.shtml"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding this BEFORE the `console.writeline`  `client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36.");`

Answer (score 3):

They ban some user agents, so you need to pretend to be a browser or something.

```cs
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "/");
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://www.bom.gov.au/vic/forecasts/ballarat.shtml"));
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you, I had a lot of anxiety around asking for help once again thanks.